# static_assert inside a macro throwing compile time errors even when it shouldn't (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, macros, static-assert

## tl;dr

When I try to compile this code, Visual Studio throws a compile time error for very `static_assert`, regardless of wheter it should, and then also one "active error" for the only one that should. This is an issue with my code, or with Visual Studio?

**Visual Studio Version**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.2

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Node {};
struct A : Node {};
struct B : Node {};

#define cast_to_A(ptr) ([&] () { \
    static_assert( \
        std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<Node>, decltype(ptr)>::value, \
        "Cannot cast to an A pointer." \
    ); \
    return std::static_pointer_cast<A>(ptr); \
})()

#define cast_to_B(ptr) ([&] () { \
    static_assert( \
        std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<Node>, decltype(ptr)>::value, \
        "Cannot cast to a B pointer." \
    ); \
    return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(ptr); \
})()

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto aAsNode = std::static_pointer_cast<Node>(a);
    auto bAsNode = std::static_pointer_cast<Node>(b);

    auto a1 = cast_to_A(aAsNode); // Expected: No error, Actual: "Cannot cast to an A pointer."
    auto b1 = cast_to_B(bAsNode); // Expected: No error, Actual: "Cannot cast to an B pointer."

    auto badCast = cast_to_A(b); // Expected & Actual: "Cannot cast to an A pointer."

    return 0;
}
```

## Context

In a personal project, I have a `node` struct from which a bunch of child structs inherit. Throughout the program I cast from `std::shared_ptr<Node>` to `std::shared_ptr<Child>` and vice-versa using `std::static_pointer_cast`. Somewhere in my program I have compile time errors where I'm acidentally trying to convert from one sibling pointer to another. However, the error is attriubted to code within `std::static_pointer_cast` (line 1925 of <memory>), and as it isn't a runtime error I can't move up the call stack to find where my bad call is.

As it happens, the code for my structs is procedurally generated by a python script I wrote. My attempted solution was to generate a macro for each struct (like seen in the toy example), then I just did a regex search/replace to replace all my `std::static_pointer_cast` calls with the appropriate macro.

The issue I have is that recreated in the toy example above. Visual Studio puts a red line under the macro "calls" that I would expect to fail (so I've actually found the bug now), but for every single use of the macro it also throws a compile time error from the `static_assert`, even when (to my understanding) it shouldn't fail. It doesn't put a red line under those "calls" though, so I'm unsure if this is a Visual Studio bug.

Looking around online saw that `std::is_same` can be quite particular about what counts as the same type or not. The variable given as the marco argument get's passed to the `static_assert` by reference (as it passes through the lambda's `[&]` capture), so I wondered if this was throwing it off. But I couldn't figure out any way to tweak the types to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help! Any pointers or tips are much appreciated!

Comment: Since you're passing the parameter to the lambda by reference, I think you might need to use [remove_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference), `decltype(std::remove_reference(ptr))`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you're exactly right! Slightly different syntax, but I got it working and now only the bad cast throws an error. The syntax was `std::remove_reference<decltype(ptr)>::type`. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1201ProgramAlarm answered in the comments. The solution was to use `std::remove_reference` to remove the reference added to the ptr when it is passed into the lambda. The final macro was:

```cpp
#define cast_to_A(ptr) ([&] () { \
    static_assert( \
        std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<Node>, std::remove_reference<decltype(ptr)>::type>::value, \
        "Cannot cast to an A pointer." \
    ); \
    return std::static_pointer_cast<A>(ptr); \
})()
```

Now only the expected "bad cast" throws an error